# Want to delay image following my mouse cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
$("#butterfly").delay(90000);
$("#butterfly").css({left:e.pageX, top:e.pageY});
   });
```

How to create delay in image following the cursor. #butterfly is 
   "img id="butterfly" element.

Answer (score 3):

Use [**setTimeout**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout), `delay` will not work with `.css()`. As it is used to delay the execution of functions that follow it in the **queue**.

```
$(document).mousemove(function (e) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#butterfly").css({
            left: e.pageX,
            top: e.pageY
        });
    }, 90000);
});
```